# A value of type 'dart.core::int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dart.core::double' when using flutter flare

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying out the new flare 2d dimensions for Flutter.

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Flare",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: FlareDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class FlareDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlareActor(
          "assets/circular.flr",
          animation: "circular",
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `circular.flr` file is created in 2d dimensions and exported as a binary for flutter. When I run the app I get error as follows

```
A value of type 'dart.core::int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dart.core::double'.
```

and the error occurs in `flare_actor.dart` file which comes from the `flare_flutter:` dependency.I am not getting any compile time error and I have included `flare_flutter:` and `circular.flr` in my `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: looks like there is an issue opened : https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/issues/6

Comment: also there is a PR fixing that issue , so you can wait or point directly to the fixed repo

Comment: Your code looks clean, must be an issue in the plugin.

Comment: @diegoveloper Thanks a lot